# функция select * into from ( select

Tags: sql, sql-server

Необходимо сгруппировать строки и записать в новую таблицу. Группировать по номеру договора, по одному договору может быть несколько раз оплата, нужно её просуммировать, не пойму где ошибка ругается на последнюю скобку. СУБД: MSSMS.

```
    select *
into #temp_qq
from 
(select [Договор],
[Точка],
sum([Оплата]) as [Оплата],
[Продавец],
[ФИО],
[Инициалы],
[Дата подписания],
[Продукт],
[Предыдущий договор],
[Следующий договор],
[Срок]
from www
group by [Договор],
[Точка],
[Оплата],
[Продавец],
[ФИО],
[Инициалы],
[Дата подписания],
[Продукт],
[Предыдущий договор],
[Следующий договор],
[Срок])
```

Comment: `Оплату` из группировки то уберите. и скобки `from ( ... )` в целом тоже не нужны.

Comment: собственно текст ругательства тоже неплохо было бы привести

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'. это после того как убрал скобки
Incorrect syntax near ')'.  это до

Comment: пардоньте. невнимательно прочитал все. вам тут вообще нужен только один внутренний селект. в нем сразу и напишите что `into #..`. Внешний селект не трубется.

Comment: а в текущем виде, наверное после `from (... ) as t` алиас надо добавить, чтобы работало.

Comment: @Андрей SSMS - SQL Server Management Studio, CУБД - MS SQL

Comment: @teran Спасибо!

Comment: оформил ответом, если помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Относительного самого запроса. У вас поле `[Оплата]` фигурирует как в группировке, так и  в самой выборке с агрегатной функцией. Чтобы суммирование проводилось корректно, необходимо убрать поле из группировки.

Относительно самого запроса. В целом у вас несколько все усложнено и здесь достаточно одного внутреннего запроса вида:

```
select a, b, sum(c) as c
into #tmp
from data 
group by a,b
```

С двумя запросами как у вас для внутреннего селекта необходимо добавить алиас

```
select *
into #tmp
from (
   select a,b, sum(c) as c
   from data
   group by a,b    
) as t
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что если я сделаю такую группировку во временную таблицу, то получу там Договор и Сумму всех оплат по нему, потом могу подтянуть эти суммы обратно по номеру договора и удалив все даты оплаты кроме последней избавиться от лишних строк?

Comment: @Андрей все зависит от данных. Если вам нужно получить только договор и общую сумму по нему, то оставьте только эти два поля в выборке , а в группировке только договор. в любом случае выполните запрос без `into #tmp` и посмотрите, каков результат ваших действий. Потом да, пронумеруте исходные строки по убыванию дат для договоров и удалите, где номер больше 1, останутся последние.

Comment: select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Договор order by [Дата] DESC) as [№ п/п], Договор, Дата
from direct_all
Запрос на нумерацию вроде пишу правильно, не получается записать это в таблицу, надо ведь сначала во временную это всё, а потом update? но мне кажется он не корректно подтягивает

Comment: @Андрей вы хотите с его помощью обновить строки с номером 1 ? Может проще сначала удалить все с номером 2 и выше? а потом остатки обновить? в CTE можете это вписать, а потом к нему апдейт написать.